# Program for mac to compare and syncronize files.

Tags: mac

I have two folders Both with same name. I would like an app that can compare the files in each and tell me the ones that have changed. I would also then like to be able to sync them so they both have the same folders and files in.

Does anyone know of a good program to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  Product/buying recommendations are considered off-topic for SU as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: Oh! sorry. Can you close the question then?

Comment: Once it gets enough close votes (5) or a Mod comes along and closes it, it will be closed.  :)

Comment: If you have Apple's Developer Tools.

FileMerge should do what I want.
It will be in /Developer/Applications/Utilities, identical files will be labeled in grey, files with differences will be in black.

Files can be sycn that way.

Answer (score 1):

`rsync` was built expressly for this. Using `-n` will tell it to only tell what it *would* copy over since the files are out of sync.